# Input field responding slowly Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt app which uses Vuetify as UI library. I've noticed that there was a delayed input in my input fields. There are lot of fields on the page then i looked at my login page which has only 2 fields. That page is also responding to input slowly. I've have some watchers in the page for other field but for the fields which doesn't have any validation and any watcher/computed properties the input is still delayed. This is happening across the app. I've tried to add `lazy` to `v-model` as  `<v-text-field v-model.lazy="neworder.description" label="Description"></v-text-field>` but no luck. Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: I had the same problem in a previous project and it seemed really annoying in development mode. Did you try to build your app to see if it is still happening in production mode?

Comment: I haven't tried that. I will give it a go and update this question. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code (script and markup)

Comment: as @Hammerbot pointed out. This was happening in development mode. Maybe due to lots of cache being accumulated over my various changes in the code. So i've cleared the cache, Restarted the browser and Restarted IDE. All went back to normal.